# How to mock call private methods in Junit5?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

```
Class A{
 public void testA(){
   // other codes
   priMethod();
   // other codes
 }

 private void priMethod(){
   // other codes
 }
}
```

I want to test testA method,The priMethod method is not the focus of the test and I want to skip it.Is there a method similar to dothing().when() ?

All I found were junit4 methods or ones that didn't work, but I wanted a junit5 solution since I couldn't change the junit version or the source code.

Comment: DONT! I have found myself in need to test private methods for 2 reasons: implementation was too complex or the class did too much. In both cases, testing through the public interface was too hard, making me want to test the private methods directly. The answer in both cases is refactor: split the complex class in 2 or more that are individually easy to unit test. How is strongly dependent on the specific case, so editing the question to add something as close to the real code as possible might help.

Comment: I can only access it not mock it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to mock private methods with Mockito

Their wiki: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mockito-And-Private-Methods

Comment: this is not an answer but only a link. Pease explain more. A link has to be a support of your answer.

Comment: This link was updated in 2017, is it still unresolved?

Answer (score 1):

It is usually not an option for mocking frameworks and Mockito is no exception.

If the private method result is irrelevant for testing the class functionality, that probably just means the class is not cohesive and it's not honoring the single responsibility principle (SRP). In other words, if you feel the need to mock a private method, that just means that the private method belongs somewhere else.

In such cases, the way forward is to extract the private method into a public or package-protected method (depending on the scenario) that lives in a separate class that can itself be tested independently.

Comment: It's a pity that the code cannot be modified